# Remove font's shadow in Sankey

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, sankey-diagram

Is it possible to remove the white shadow of the font in the following sankey diagram?

[image]

```
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    
    fig = go.Figure(go.Sankey(
        arrangement = "snap",
        node = {
            "label": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
            "x": [0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.5],
            "y": [0.7, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3],
            'pad':10},  # 10 Pixels
        link = {
            "source": [0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 5],
            "target": [5, 3, 4, 3, 0, 2, 2, 3],
            "value": [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]}))
    
    fig.show()
```

Comment: I have the opposite problem: When writing the plot to PNG I lose the shadows and labels become invisible in cluttered areas. Quite a string thing, these shadows...

Answer (score 3):

It certainly seems to ***not*** be possible. You can edit *some* text attributes through `f['data'][0]['textfont']` like:

```
sankey.Textfont({
'color': '#2a3f5f', 'family': '"Open Sans", verdana, arial, sans-serif', 'size': 10
})
```

And as you can see `sankey.Textfont` has no attribute that can edit the properties of the "shadow". I've tried setting other values for `'family'` but the shadow persists no matter what. Another peculiar detail here seems to be that the color can't be changed directly either. Only `'size'` and `'family'`

Answer (score 0):

I had a more dramatic problem with this. I had the labels set to be transparent, to not clutter the plot but still be visible when hovering. I ended up with the white shadow covering up about half of the plot!

I was able to override the css in the html header. You can even write out the plot as a div tag and set the html around it to include the style tag in the head. You presumably will need a different css class for your case. You can use your browser's developer mode to inspect and find it.

This requires saving the figure to html. You could write it out (possibly to a temporary file) and use the [webbrowser module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) to get the same effect as `fig.show()`.

If you are writing to SVG, probably something similar will work, but I haven't tried it out.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.node-label {
  text-shadow: unset !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<html>
```

Then write the div block:

```
fig.write_html(f, full_html=False)
```

Finally, complete the document:

```
</body>
</html>
```

In a pinch, or for a one-off, you can edit the html to add the style block to the head.